# Is it possible to put portable air conditioner outside the house?

Tags: air-conditioning

I don't know if this has been done before, because because I rent, can not do any installation therefore a slip and window A/C is not an option for me and only portable is okay. But I heard that the portable is noisy.

So I wonder if it is possible to put the outside in the backyard (my window faces the backyard) and make some modification to the portable A/C by connecting the cold air to the hose through the window into the room.

Is that possible?

Comment: You can't have a window unit, but you can have this thing sitting outside? Where someone can steal it...? Is the rule simply that you cannot have AC units sticking out of your windows or that you cannot modify, in anyway, the apartment? What will you stick in the window to block around the vents which would be any different than a window unit that isn't screwed in?

Answer (score 2):

There are commercial units designed for this application, there should be no reason you could not convert yours for it.

However, you should consider:

- if your unit is rated for indoor use only, you will be voiding the warranty and possible creating a shock/electrocution hazard; use a G.F.C.I. please
- UV damage caused by exposure to sunlight, consider a shade structure
- restriction of factory vent ports by McGyvering duct work to it may cause sub-optimal performance or may cause damage to the unit
- air inlet exposure to outdoor dust and debris could affect the unit

[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

You just need to have two pipes running in to your room. One that sucks the air in to the machine (you could just have it sucking in air from outside, but that wouldn't be efficient), and one for the cooled air coming back in to your room.  Make sure you insulate both pipes as best as you can, so that the cool air doesn't lose its coolness. Also ensure you have a good seal for the pipes where they enter your room.

Have you tried it since? If so, please share your experience!